# Automatically change Visual Studio 2010 Source Control Provider (using Macro/Plug-in)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba, version-control, visual-studio-macros

It is a common scenario for me nowadays to work on projects that use different source control providers. For example, SVN, Mercurial, etc.

I feel the plug-ins should automatically detect the source control used for a project and should take over automatically. But sadly, that's not the case. Everytime, I load a project, I have to go to options and change Source Control plug-in.

I was thinking of writing a macro or a plug-in to do that for me.

I was looking for a name of property to change in *DTE.Properties*, but could not find any in related property in registry @`HKCU/Software/Mircosoft/VisualStudio/10.0_Config`.

I am looking for an advise on this.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Check out: https://scs.codeplex.com/

Haven't used it personally, but seems to fit your needs.